# Google Analytics Privacy Policy When Storing UK Postcode or City With Custom Dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics, privacy, privacy-policy, custom-dimensions

I am aware that you can not store any individually identifiable information in Google Analytics. I am currently scoping some updates and I wondering if storing a full UK Postcode or City within Custom Dimensions would be against GA's Privacy Policy?

So which would be allowed and not allowed and why?

- City (London, Manchester, etc)
- Half Postcode (EC1V, E2, S17)
- Full Postcode (EC2V 9GG, S22 9UU)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a subjective question and grey area, but that said, you should ultimately consult your privacy lawyers (if you have them) on what is deemed as "personally identifiable information" (PII) or not. For what it's worth, here are my thoughts:

- City - Not PII. You should have no problems collecting this information. It cannot be used to identify a specific individual.
- Half Postcode - Not PII. I couldn't perceive this as being able to identify an individual, so I think you'd be safe here.
- Full Postcode - here's where it might be tricky. Normally I would say this is not PII, and should be OK, but there could be the case where a single dwelling is assigned it's own postal code, and hence it becomes personally identifiable. How likely is that though, really? Probably not likely, but you never know. Here is where you should contact a better authority on privacy issues. Best would be to just avoid collecting this altogether.

Comment: Thanks for this, its a very helpful answer. I would assume you are correct about Full Postcode. Might not be worth the risk.